# How do I add custom panel themes to Lubuntu Artful Aardvark?

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10

I'm *kinda* new with this whole themeing thing on Lubuntu. I can add cursors easily, but I'm unsure how to add themes to the panel. Anyone know how?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/theme-up-lubuntu/) link.

Comment: Maybe this: https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel_Theming